R crashes when running R's terra and Julia's GeoArrays.jl packages in R simultaneously via JuliaCall
I want to run some code in R that uses the terra package to handle rasters. At the same time, from R, I need to be able to load rasters into memory in Julia using GeoArrays.jl. On MacOS and Windows, everything works. On linux, both of these operations work in isolation. But when you load the terra R package and GeoArrays.jl in the same R session you start crashing R.
I think this is due to different geospatial libraries (e.g., GDAL) being used. I think terra uses the system libraries in /usr while GeoArrays uses libraries in .julia/artifacts. For example, .julia/artifacts/46c5acbd05a78b6bc9dc0e68fe5305cb2976e252/lib in my docker container contains "cmake", "gdalplugins", "libgdal.so", "libgdal.so.35"       "libgdal.so.35.3.9.1" and "pkgconfig".
How can I configure R or Julia to use the same libraries? Solutions configuring R to use Julia's libraries or Julia to use R's libraries are welcome!
Reprex
R-side set up
install.packages("terra")
library(terra)

Julia-side set up
rstudio@9e9f75e5bc94:~$ julia
(@v1.9) pkg> add GeoArrays
julia> using GeoArrays

Playing together
# Set up
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()

library(terra)
julia_library('GeoArrays')

# Two example rasters

> system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/terra/ex/elev.tif"

> system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/terra/ex/logo.tif"

# terra::rast() works
terra::rast("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/terra/ex/elev.tif")

# GeoArrays.read() crashes R when also using terra!
julia_command('GeoArrays.read("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/terra/ex/logo.tif")')

Docker
I am trying this on a Apple M2 Pro running Sonoma 14.5 using Docker.
Dockerfile
# RStudio Server
# https://rocker-project.org/images/versioned/rstudio.html
# Based on r/r-ver which builds on Ubuntu LTS
FROM rocker/rstudio

# Install system dependencies
# * With libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev, install.packages("terra") and library(terra) works
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libgmp-dev patchelf \
    libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev

# Install Julia
RUN wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.9/julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvzf julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    mv julia-1.9.2 /opt/julia && \
    ln -s /opt/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia && \
    rm julia-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

# Install selected R packages
RUN R -e 'install.packages("rstudioapi")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("glue")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("JuliaCall")'

Build the image
To build the docker image, I use:
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t r-julia .

The --platform linux/amd64 tag seems to fix a Julia launch error in the container:
rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Run the container
To run the container, use:
docker run -e USERID=$(id -u) -e GROUPID=$(id -g) -it --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=pwd r-julia

Then in your browser, use http://localhost:8787 to launch RStudio.
The username is rstudio and the password is pwd.
Then you can run the code above.
